# Replace content tag html in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, regex, ckeditor

I get content in ckeditor by command

`var content = $('#editor1').val(); // With editor1 is my ckeditor`

And I receive a string like `<h3 class="Interview">any word(may be unicode)</h3>`
How can I replace it to `<h3 class="Interview">My word</h3>` by javascript ????

Please help me !!! Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
result = subject.replace(/(<[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>)([a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*)(<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>)/, "$1 My words $3");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make that by using regexp:

```
var a = '<h3 class="Interview">any word(may be unicode)</h3>'
a = a.replace(/(<h3[^>]*>)[^<]*<\/h3>/g, '$1'+'your words</h3>')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var str="<h3 class=\"Interview\">any word(may be unicode)</h3>";

function htmlTextReplace(original){
    var regex = />([^<]*)</g;
    return original.replace(regex, function($0, $1){
      return $0.replace($1, strTextReplace($1, 'any word','your words'));
    });
 }

function strTextReplace(str, ow, dw){
    return str.replace(ow, dw);
}
console.log(htmlTextReplace(str));
```